# some libraries are missing in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, package-management, c++, mysql-workbench

I want to install MySQL Workbench Community,but in terminal when I attempt to install It always says to me libnetcdf6 is missing and gives error. I tried to find this but It is just available on 12.04. How can I install this library on 14.04 ?

Comment: try installing it from software center. software center will take care of dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-minimal

Assuming all goes well, we can now update without issue

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: this doesn't work